# i am implementing a code to search a string ending with semicolon(;) and output should be as below example?

Tags: c++, string

i am implementing a code to search a string ending with semicolon(;) and output should be as below example

```
  Example char buffer[]="125;37;9" 
  output should be as= found:125,found:37,found:9
```

but my code output is= found:125,found:375,found:975 because it is storing  previous value  my code is below please help me to fix it thank you

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<string>
  using namespace std;
  string Arrange_tel(char *);
 int main()
      {
        int size;
        cout<<"enetr size"<<endl;
        cin>>size;
        char ch[size];

      cout<<"eneter string" <<endl ;
     cin>>ch;
    cout<<Arrange_tel(ch)<<endl;
  }
    string Arrange_tel(char *p)
{
      int i=0;
      char temp[100]="";
      string store_tel;
      string tel="tel:";
      while(*p!='\0')
   {
        if(*p!=';')
            {
             temp[i]= *p;
            }

            else
            {
                temp[i]=',';

                store_tel.append(tel);
                store_tel.append(temp);
                   i=-1;
            }

            i++;
            p++;
     }
       store_tel.append(tel);
       store_tel.append(temp);
       return store_tel;
     }
```

Comment: From your post it is not clear whether a semicolon has to be indeed substituted for a comma or only word "found" is added to the string.

Comment: Another question is why are you using a character array insted of class std::string to enter a string?

Comment: Why would there be *three* `found` prependages when there were only two semicolons in the input string? Further, why would the second `found` sequence end in semicolon rather than a comma in your sample "correct" output?

Answer (score 0):

The while  loop needs to look something like this:

```
while (*p != '\0')
{
    if (*p != ';')
    {
        temp[i] = *p;
        i++;
        p++;
    }

    else
    {
        temp[i] = ',';
        temp[i+1] = '\0'; // null terminate temp.

        store_tel.append(tel);
        store_tel.append(temp);
        i = 0;
        p++;
    }
}
```

But this program has some serious flaws, the most glaring of which is the ability to overrun the char arrays.

Since this question is tagged C++, we should be able to take advantage of some of the things C++ will do for us. I have preserved tel: from the OP's code in place of the found used in OP's description.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
string Arrange_tel(const string & p)
{
    stringstream tokenizer(p); //make a stream out of the input 
    string token;
    stringstream store_tel; // make a stream for the output.
    while (getline(tokenizer, token, ';')) // grab everything up to the next ; 
                                           // or the end of the stream
    {
        store_tel << "tel:"; 
        store_tel << token << ',';
    }
    return store_tel.str();
}

int main()
{
    string ch;
    cout << "enter string" << endl;
    cin >> ch;
    cout << Arrange_tel(ch) << endl;
}
```

But I hate the trailing comma. We hit the end of the input, not a ; to replace. Plus it looks stupid. If you want it gone, replace the while loop with this:

```
if (getline(tokenizer, token, ';')) //grab first token and output without ,
{
    store_tel << "tel:"; // note the lack of a comma
    store_tel << token;
    while (getline(tokenizer, token, ';'))
    { // output the rest with a preceding comma
        store_tel << ",tel:"; //note the comma
        store_tel << token;
    }
}
```